# Python, advice on grouping functions

Tags: python, module

I have a project, simulating numerics for my diploma thesis in physics, I think one should call this a rather small project... there might be maybe a hundred functions in the end (each doing some rather small logical block).

Somehow, I'm reluctant to put this all into a package, it feels "too big" a tool (and also it feels nicer to have just some text files importing each other than a more complex folder structure)

**Is there a reason not to use classes with `@staticmethod`s instead of grouping your functions into packages?**

In short: I want to have more then one level of nested functions (not just file -> function), because in this case I have to search for the correct names and type them each time. It should be like: type np. -> get a list in the editor -> chose linalg. -> get a list -> chose function. Is this possible without building a package, as indicated above?

I hope this question is not just a matter of opinion but sufficiently "answerable". Sorry if not.

Comment: How is a text file that you import different from a module?

Comment: ...oh, sorry, I meant a packages, thank you. I'll explain in an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group you functions into modules without creating a class to hold a bunch of static methods.   you would only want to go that route if you felt there were instances of the class you were creating and there was a need to act outside the instance level (maybe on a list of instances or setting some global variable that is used in creation of the instances).   based on your description it sounds more like you need to head with organizing the functions into modules (possibly by responsibility or data acted on in the overall program).

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, my wording was wrong, I meant package rather than module.
Yes, I have thought a lot about how to organize by logic and the data they ant upon :) I have an instance of an object (a honeycomb lattice of sites), but also a lot of function that act upon it or other data. 
I think in your answer I get a better idea about what staticmethods are made for; but I had the idea to abuse the object structure to group non-instance-related functions

Comment: I would only keep object behavior with the instances.   Class methods should relate to the objects behavior in some way (access, creation, class level information about all the objects).   Put your business logic that is not part of the class in its own modules.   you can organize in packages if that makes sense based on size and responsibilities of the code.   If you like my answer please upvote or accept as an answer.  Thanks.

Comment: well, both answers are not really what I wanted to ask about. But maybe I begin to understand how to state the question more precisely... ok, I'll accept it since it helped to understand a little more what those things are meant for

Answer (score 0):

Static method is something used by OOP, functions are used in structural programming. Since OOP is modern - you know, what I'm trying to say. All in all - that is an entry in a dict structure...

To me - group by logic, not the purpose. For instance some projects have subdirectories for models, views, and controllers. If you try to change user functionality - you are supposed to look around, since functionality is in different locations. I know that html templates are located separately to make webmaster's work easier.

Comment: Thank you ... but "you know, what I'm trying to say" - no, I don't, sorry :)
I use OOP because it seems to make the ordering and structuring easier, and because I have an object that is logically an object. But nonetheless my structuring turned too messy, so I want to have more nested paths to functions

Comment: Some people likes something new just because it is new. Some people would like to use common approach. So OOP is new, and static method gives them filling that it is common world. With langs like Java it is hard to find alternative. With Python - looks ok for me